# Android Phones Default Shell

Tags: android, linux, unix

What is the default built in shell in Android phones and can I run [runtime.exec](/questions/tagged/runtime.exec) Java method without installing a shell ?

Answer (score 0):

You can call runtime.exec(String) in Android but it won't get you very far, because the runtime doesn't really offer commands to consume. However, if you've got a rooted phone with busybox and su installed, it is possible to call those embedded commands. It's even possible to create a superuser session by executing the su binary and consuming the streams of it.